# Validation of the youtube address

Tags: php

I have to do a plugin that allows you to insert videos from youtube in website. For this purpose I have encountered a problem, I want to validate the correctness of the url address from youtube. I want to check the correctness of the address, under the account:
- check if the id of the movie is included in the address
- Check if the address contains (youtube.com or youtu.be)

My code only checks if the url contains (youtu.be or youtube.com). I do not know how to check if the address has a movie id of 11 characters long. Do you have any idea?

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knfrxj0T5NY';
if (strpos($url, 'youtube.com') || strpos($url, 'youtu.be')){
    echo 'ok';
}else{
    echo 'no';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method using cURL:

```
function isValidYoutubeURL($url) {
    // Let's check the host first
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if (!in_array($host, array('youtube.com', 'www.youtube.com'))) {
        return false;
    }

    $ch = curl_init('www.youtube.com/oembed?url='.urlencode($url).'&format=json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);

    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return ($status !== 404);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, try to change the state of this question to solved then. :)